# リンク先のページは何をしているのですか？ 「schema.org/SearchResultsPage」？　「local.google.com/place?id」？

Tags: html

リンク先のページは何ですか？
普通のHTMLですか？
それとも何か特殊なことをしているのですか？

https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=h%C2%B0m%27s%22+archive+%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E6%96%B0%E5%AE%BF%E5%BA%97&ludocid=8547527681459461297&lpsid=3486988130797668852&source=sh/x/localposts&lsig=AB86z5VL-Sc40AMfw35fLqlIcQdx

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage"
```

このパラメータは何を指定しているのですか？
ludocid=
&lpsid=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通のHTMLです。[マイクロデータ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Microdata)が使われていますね。

> このパラメータは何を指定しているのですか？

それはGoogleに聞かないとわかりません。

Comment: userが作成したページではなく、Googleが勝手に作成しているページということですか？

Comment: google.co.jp のページですからGoogleが責任を持つのは間違いないですが、どうやってデータを作ったかはGoogleに聞かないとわかりません。stackoverflowで聞くよりは https://support.google.com/websearch/community?hl=ja で聞いたほうが詳しい人が多いでしょう。

Comment: なるほど、URLは確かに「https://www.google.co.jp/search?」ですね